# Xml Tag base64Binary C#

Tags: c#, xml, base64

Tenho a seguinte tag xml (vou resumir por questão de tamanho):

```
<docZip schema="procNFe_v3.10.xsd" NSU="000000000001868">H4sIAAAAAAAEAN1aWY+jyLJ+Pv..bla bla bla</docZip>
```

O tipo do campo é base64Binary, é um arquivo Gzip.

Já revirei a internet procurando uma forma de "ler" o XML e pegar esta tag e gerar o arquivo Gzip que está contido nela.

Como faço para pegar esta tag que está em base64Binary e gerar o arquivo que está contido?

Testei com esse código de exemplo porem sem sucesso:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Base64Decoder
{
  public static void Main ()
  {
        string inputText = "This is some text.";
        Console.Out.WriteLine ("Input text: {0}", inputText);
        byte [] bytesToEncode = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (inputText);

        string encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String (bytesToEncode);
        Console.Out.WriteLine ("Encoded text: {0}", encodedText);

        byte [] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String (encodedText);
        string decodedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (decodedBytes);
        Console.Out.WriteLine ("Decoded text: {0}", decodedText);

        Console.Out.Write ("Press enter to finish.");
        Console.In.ReadLine ();

        return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, eu tentaria fazer da seguinte forma:

```
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String("H4sIAAAAAAAEAN1aWY+jyLJ+Pv..bla bla bla");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\home\arquivo.rar", buffer);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

*Resposta editada a partir de mensagem postada abaixo para facilitar a outros com a mesma dúvida.*

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porem o arquivo gerado está vazio. Porem gerei com o código File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\home\arquivo.rar", buffer); mas sua resposta resolveu minha duvida.

Comment: Ok Robss, não foi nada. Tomei a liberdade de editar minha resposta para que outras pessoas pudessem ter acesso a um código funcional, creio que seja mais "pedagógico". Abraço

Comment: Valeu jovem....

Answer (score 1):

Galera usei a base deste tópico para me ajudar, e nada mais justo que compartilhar um ajuste, pois o conteúdo que vem da tag  é um xml então para a conversão direta fiz o seguinte:

```
        String base64 = "H4sIAAAAAAAEAIVSXW+CMBT9K4Z3...";

        byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        byte[] xmlret = Decompress(buffer);

        File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\retorno.xml", xmlret);
```

O metodo Decompress:

```
        static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzip)
        {
           using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new 
           MemoryStream(gzip),CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            const int size = 4096;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                }
                while (count > 0);
                return memory.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

Espero que ajude mais pessoas!